# PHP Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted

Tags: php, memory, mpdf

I'm using mPDF library to create and download PDF files, for example x1000 (singly using ajax) in loop.
Sometimes I get error message for series of files `"Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261900 bytes)"`. I read that I have to set bigger memory_limit in configuration but I can't do this, because 256M is my limit.

**Is there any other solution for this error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce memory usage two other ways without increasing the memory limit...

1. [Consider setting $mpdf->simpleTables = true; if you do not need complex table borders, or $mpdf->packTableData = true; if you do not mind the extra processing time.](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=406)
2. [packTableData – Use binary packing of table data to reduce memory usage](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=444)

Both of which will increase processing time in order to save memory usage.

Comment: First solution allowed me to save 5MB. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in a test environment with higher memory limit, to ensure that the problem is a memory limit issue. Maybe you have an infinite loop or an infinite recursive call that is consuming your memory.

Comment: I am sure that there is no infinite loop. I tried it on localhost (where memory_limit = 128M) and there was no problem with this..